# How to call in plugin options in jquery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently  using the following plugin: http://pgwjs.com/pgwslideshow/ . I am currently new to jquery and plugins so I'm using this simple plugin to exercise my abilities. I notice that there is a option to make the pictures fade instead of sliding. I'm trying to implement that on my website but not sure on how to go on about that. This is what I have so far:

```
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jQuery.Brazzers-Carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="pgwslideshow.min.css">
 <script src="jQuery.Brazzers-Carousel.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="pgwslideshow.min.js"></script>

<style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    body {
        <!--background: -webkit-linear-gradient(yellow, blue, yellow);
        -->
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
Here are some cool jobs you can get with this degree:
<ul class="pgwSlideshow">
<li>
<img src="http://3vxsjq3roj103wlhf71jhh7t.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/computer-nerd.jpeg"
alt="Software Engineer" data-description="Average salary: £37k">
</li>
<li>
<img src="http://www.alphasoftware.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Full-stack-Mobile-App-Developer-Job-in-LA.jpg" 
alt="Mobile Developer" data-description="Average salary: £33k">
</li>
<li>
<img src="http://waqas.club/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/web-developer-lahore.png" 
alt="Web Developer" data-description="Average salary: £24k">
</li>
<li>
<img src="https://sourcemaking.com/files/sm/images/architect.jpg" 
alt="Software Architect" data-description="£62k">
</li>
<li>
<img src="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/money/.element/img/1.0/sections/mag/moneymag/bestjobs/2010/snapshot/049_systems_engineer.ju.jpg"
alt="Systems Enginner" data-description="£40k">
</li>


</ul>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".thumb-item").brazzersCarousel();
        $(".pgwSlideshow").pgwSlideshow();
        transitionEffect:'fading';

});



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm using Bootstrap to make the layout of the page. Long story short,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".thumb-item").brazzersCarousel();
        $(".pgwSlideshow").pgwSlideshow({
            transitionEffect:'fading'
        });    
});
```

You need the put the options as an object for the function argument.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. It worked. Do you also know how to override a style of a plugin? I am currently using this tooltiip plugin: http://www.jqueryrain.com/?Faul9WEm